# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘SSL’ {aka ‘struct ssl_st’}

Tags: c++, c, pointers, ssl, openssl

I am migrating some code from openssl1.0.x to openssl1.1.1k.

I am gtting error-

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘SSL’ {aka ‘struct ssl_st’}
```

code-

```
SSL *s;

if((op == 0 || op == 1) && (NULL != s->s3->rbuf.buf))
{
    OPENSSL_free(s->s3->rbuf.buf);
    s->s3->rbuf.buf = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1 made many structures private so that applications no longer rely on specific undocumented internals and then break if these internals change (like they did with OpenSSL 3.0.0). I'm not sure what this code was trying to do in the first place but the internal buffers will automatically be freed when the SSL object is freed so there should be no need to do this by hand in the first place.